# Server Database Working But trying Connect Local Db Not Working In MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working in ASP.NET MVC5 project. My application has perfectly wodrked with non-local server DB. However, I've created local DB, but it's not connecting to `Local Db` . `Local DB` is  not working, but server DB is working.

Here is my connection string and Connection from AppSettings:

Here My code connection string code Here Attach

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<appSettings>

  <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="DefaultTheme" value="Theme1"/>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="TickPortalSql" value="Server=10.0.0.1;Database=montage;User ID=user;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;"/>
  <!--<add key="TickPortalSql" value="Server=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;Database=montagenew;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=False;" />-->
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.LoginUrl" value="/Account/LogOn" />
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Name" value=".CUSTOM_AUTH" />
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Expiration" value="1" />
  <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Timeout" value="20" />
</appSettings>
```

If I connect to `LocalDB`, it's  not working. The error is:

> Login failed for user ''.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed
>   for user ''.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 70:                 if (parameters != null)
> Line 71:                 {
> Line 72:                     result = await db.QueryAsync<TModel>(sql: procname, param:
> ```
>
> BuildQueryParameter(parameters), commandType:
>   CommandType.StoredProcedure);
>       Line 73:                 }
>       Line 74:                 else

My Web Config:

```
<connectionStrings>      
  <add name="montageEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entityframework.Model1.csdl|res://*/Entityframework.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Entityframework.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=198.71.227.2;initial catalog=montage;user id=Montage;password=******3;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Please Help I have Stuck with this error.

Comment: And this should fix your issue `DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;Database=montagenew;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=False;`

take note of SSPI,

Comment: i am getting same error @Desperado

Answer (score 0):

```
<add key="TickPortalSql" value="Data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=montagenew;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=False;" />

<add key="TickPortalSql" value="Data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=montagenew;User Id=yourUserId; Password=yourPassword" />
```

Try both of code. If I helped please mark this as answer.

Comment: i am not using local sql server  username and password @Sandip

Comment: try first one. If something goes wrong. Comment that here. I will try to fix that same at my local computer.

Comment: sure i will try here